# how to select all rows of a local database table

Tags: c#, sql

[image]

I have a table "Entry" and it has columns "vehicle" and "arrival_time". I have set the present time to DateTime.Now . Now I want to check values in every row for the column "arrival_time". If "arrival_time" exceeds present time, then  value of  "vehicle" from that particular row is inserted into a new table "Update". If this condition is true for multiple rows, those rows must be inserted into the next table at a single button click.

I have searched many sites and youtube videos but I am not getting any satisfying answer. Please help. I am working in windows form application c#.

This code selects just one row.

Comment: Break it down into 2 tasks. 1) Selecting the desired vehicles based on arrival_time. 2) Updating the other table. You should be able to find numerous examples of how to do both of those tasks individually.

Comment: string query = "SELECT arrival_time FROM Entry";
                dt = cn.retrieve(query);
                DateTime time = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[0][0]);
                string query1 = "select vehicle_no from Entry";
                dt = cn.retrieve(query1);
                string vehicle = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
           //  if the expected time exceed the current time
        
               if (time <= DateTime.Now)
             {
             string query2 = "insert into Alert(vehicle_no) values('" + vehicle + "')";
              cn.manipulate(query2);
            }

Comment: Why are you trying to do that in C#. Surely it would be better to put all of that in a stored procedure and call the stored procedure. That would be so much better than multiple calls to the database

Comment: Thanks for answering Simon. As you can see I have done the part that you have suggested. The problem is I am able to do it only with one row. Can you write me the syntax to select all the rows.

Comment: As a general note, it's better to put the code inside a code block rather than pasting a screenshot.  This helps when searching, and also for users with disabilities.  See more: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: I am new to c# and to this site. Thanks for the suggestion. I will follow it from next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a stored procedure and use this :

```
INSERT INTO Alert
SELECT  vehicle_no
FROM    Entry
WHERE   arrival_time > GETDATE()
```

then call the sproc from your code.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't post code as an image, takes longer to transcribe for me

This is an altered version that will do all of the `INSERTS` in one fell swoop, and avoids all of the network chit-chat involved with performing the logic within your application.

As I do not know what methods are available via `cn`, I just wrote using ADO.
An addition that I made is the `InsertQuantity` variable, which will return the "rows affected" value that SQL returns, and if there is an error in execution it will be set to -1;

```
private void RefreshBtn_Click(object Sender, EventArgs e) {
    int InsertQuantity;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnection)) {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()) {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT Alert(Vehicle_no) SELECT Vehicle_no FROM Entry WHERE arrival_time <= GetDate()";

            try {
                conn.Open();
                InsertQuantity = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch {
                InsertQuantity = -1;
                // whatever error handling you need
            }
            finally { conn.Close(); }
        }
    }
    // InsertQuantity will tell you how many "alerts" were added
    // If  = -1 then there was an error
}
```

Comment: no need for `conn.Close()` (and therefore neither for the `finally` block): you correctly wrapped conn in a `using` statement, so connection will be properly disposed (and therefore closed) in every case

Comment: I understand that @Gian, I find that `finally` is underused and make sure I always use it when showing `try...catch` routines to reinforce that it exists.